# Software Control

Tags: version-control

Can anyone recommend any software control packages (free), specifically for web development. something that we could install on our own server. We're building a number of websites each week and I'm finding myself fixing the same bugs over and over again.

I've done a bit of research, but found people are using a number of different packages and none of them seem to jump out.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: What do you mean by "software control package"? I have never heard the term. Could you explain in more detail what you expect this software to do for you? And what do you mean by "fixing the same bugs over and over again"? Bugs in the configuration, in customer scripts, in different versions of an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your experience and needs you should check out Git, Mercurial or SVN. I've been using SVN for web apps for a few years but that doesn't have local repositories. SVN is simple to setup and use as are the others.

Mercurial is like SVN with local repositories (massive over simplification here).

Git is used by a lot of new open source projects and indeed some major ones.

If you have the time, you should really evaluate them all and find which fits your needs. If you just need simple version control and nothing fancy, then svn will fit the bill.

Though, for my own part I'm considering using Git and GitHub fairly soon and making the transtion.

Comment: Thanks very much Simon, I'll start with those recommendations.

Comment: Those are the big 3, these days. The dark horse, of course, is Perforce.

Comment: Perforce became very popular in large coprorations like Google because it is not open source, is fast at branching and merging and has good support. However TFS is way much powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But to get a more clear image of what you might need I suggest you to read a bit about configuration management:

> **[Software Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CI (countinous integration) then have a look at Team City, they have free license as well. It is really good for build /version automation and unit testing. It also provides integration with popular VCS